# Any way to specify pre and post SSRS execution script?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to run some setup SQLs before the content of my report is being processed and then at the end run some cleanup SQLs. e.g. some ALTER statements at the beginning and revert the ALTER at the end.

These should be run per report and users will be accessing the reports via the web url of the report server. I wonder if these SQLs can be configured in the report definition file.rdl using BIDS or I can configure this on the SSRS server side or the underlying database. And how?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve though your use of Alter?

Comment: I would look at making it a part of the stored procedure that returns the data for the report.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks. Thats totally doable but also means I will be altering per dataset. Was thinking if its possible to do pre and post scripts as within a report there can be multiple dataset.

Comment: @Ewan, alter is just an example. The possibilities are more, for example temp table creation and removal at the end.

Answer (score 1):

First I should say that you may not have the best process if you need to ALTER a table back and forth for a query but I know that crazy stuff is sometimes necessary.

You can add DDL statements to your dataset query.

Here's a query for a **Dataset** I have that creates a **Temp** table and some other processes before **SELECT**ing the data needed.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_CENSUS(
    GEO_DATA GEOMETRY NOT NULL,
    VALUE DECIMAL(12, 4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    NAME NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    GEO  NVARCHAR(250) NULL     ) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO #TEMP_CENSUS(GEO_DATA, VALUE, NAME)
exec dbo.CreateHeatMap 20, 25, ...
```

Unfortunately, you want other operations **after** your data is selected. For your reverting ALTER statements, you would want to create another dataset using the same source with the alter statements.

In your DataSource, check the **Use Single Transaction** box so that the two datasets will be performed in order (as they appear in the Dataset list) so your first dataset will ALTER the tables you need then SELECT your data. Then the second query will run to unALTER (re/de -ALTER?) the tables. You **may** need to add a SELECT of some sort to the second dataset query so it has some data so SSRS doesn't freak out - I haven't had to run any DDL without returning data (yet).

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try and reply back.

Comment: Ah bad luck, it said ALTER cannot be run in a transaction. But also tried without the transaction tick, seemed there is no particular order. So not working.

Comment: Ahh - I didn't know that you couldn't use ALTER in a transaction. And without the Transaction box, they dataset run at the same time. I think the only other alternative to try is to have a **Stored Procedure** ALTER the table and call the **SP** in the same way. If that's not possible then you may need to create a #Temp table with the extra column you need.